# ConcurrentModificationException on different named Models from the same TDB dataset

Tags: java, jena

I'm currently adapting a program that was working with JENA in memory Models but breaks when I try to use TDB to store different named models. I think the resulting behaviour is a bug in JENA, but maybe I'm wrong in my assumptions about named models in the same TDB.

To exhibit the behaviour, let's say that I populate a model, then I copy it to another.

```
  private void init(Model aBox) {
    aBox.setNsPrefix("foaf", FOAF.getURI());

    aBox.createResource("http://kaiko.getalp.org/test_person__1", FOAF.Person);
    aBox.createResource("http://kaiko.getalp.org/test_person__2", FOAF.Person);
    aBox.createResource("http://kaiko.getalp.org/test_person__3", FOAF.Person);
  }

  private void copy(Model aBox, Model xBox) {
    StmtIterator persons =
            aBox.listStatements(null, RDF.type, FOAF.Person);
    while (persons.hasNext()) {
      Statement next = persons.next();
      Resource p = xBox.createResource(next.getSubject().getURI());
      xBox.add(xBox.createStatement(p, RDF.type, FOAF.Person));
    }
  }
```

I now apply this behaviour on Default Models and it seems to work as expected.

```
  @Test
  public void concurrentModifWhenNoModif() throws IOException {
    Model aBox = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    Model xBox = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

    init(aBox);
    copy(aBox, xBox);
  }
```

But when I am trying to use 2 Models backed by the same TDB, it raises a `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
  @Test
  public void concurrentModifWhenNoModifOnTDB() throws IOException {
    Path temp = Files.createTempDirectory("jenatest");
    temp.toFile().deleteOnExit();
    String tdbDir = temp.toAbsolutePath().toString();
    Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(tdbDir);
    Model aBox = dataset.getNamedModel("MyNamedModel/");
    Model xBox = dataset.getNamedModel("OtherNamedModel");

    init(aBox);
    copy(aBox, xBox);
  }
```

My understanding is that I iterate on the aBox model and the xBox model is modified and I don't understand why the fact that they share a common TDB backend makes them inter-dependant on the model level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataset.getNamedModel` returns a view of the data in the dataset, and does not copy the data out. `aBox` and `xBox` share the dataset. Apps can't iterate and update the database at the same time.

In fact, this is true in many places in Jena because models can be composites of other models so share data (e.g. Inference models).

There is an operation `model1.add(model2)` to copy one model into another.

Comment: OK, I understand the Write Once Multiple Read policy means Write Once xor MultipleRead and that the scope of this rule expands to the underlying dataset. The example was here to illustrate the behaviour but copying the model was not really my need.